# couldn't fix my header using CSS

Tags: css, html, dreamweaver

I'm using HTML to build my website.
my problem is that I can't put my logo in the right of my page I have tried a lot by changing the margin but I couldn't,now **my LOGO** is on top of the sentence **our Space**

what I want is :

**English French                    our space   imageLOGO**

My html is:

```
<div id="header">

 <div >
            <img class="imgPosition"  src="images/MyLogo.jpg" alt=""/>
            <a href="index.html" class="logo"> <h1><span>Our Space </span></h1></a>

             <span><a href="HomeFrench.html" class="logolang1">French</a> <a href="HomeEnglish.html" class="logolang2">English</a></span>
</div>
</div>




#header div .imgPosition{
    alignment-adjust:middle;
    margin: 0 0 0 650px;
    height: 60px;
    width:100;
}
#header div .logo{
    color: #fff;
    /*display: block;*/
    float:right;
    margin: 0 0 0px -600px ;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#header div .logolang1 {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    float:left;
    margin: 0 0 0 -700px ;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#header div .logolang2 {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    float:left;
    margin: 0 0 0 -750px ;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: have you tried adding float right to #header div .imgPosition ?

Comment: not sure I understand what you want to accomplish.  You want the links/image to be all right aligned, or some on the left, some in the middle, and some on the right side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to place the logo to the right just change

```
alignment-adjust:middle;
```

to

```
float : right;
```

or you can make the logo a background :

```
#header{
 background : url('images/myLogo.jpg') right no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for aligning image in right jst do:

```
 <div class="image"><img class="imgPosition"  src="http://vectips.com/wp-content/themes/Vectips/images/vectips_logo.png" alt=""/></div>
```

this should do your problem. then put **margins** according to your need